# How to inject environment variables to a pipeline from another job jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

So I have two jobs, one job creates a `.properties` file, and **builds the second job (which is a pipeline)** by using this option:

[image]

Here I specify a properties file to pass into the pipeline. What I don't know is what settings to put into the pipeline to "inject" these parameters.

**The pipeline has no parameters to begin with**. I want to inject those from the properties file into the pipeline. Usuaully I would use the inject enviroment variables plugin but I do not see it here. I don't think it is supported with pipeline jobs.

How do I input these paramaters into the pipeline, and how would I call them? `${env:param}, env.param`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an actual Properties object, this should work:

```
Set propSet = properties.entrySet()

propSet.each {
    def key = it.getKey()
    def value = it.getValue()

    env."${key}" = value
}
```

Now you can access them directly in your build using the property name.